# Rails - how can I view my SQLite tables?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rails-console

I would think that there would be more information on this particular topic, but here goes -- I need to be able to see what my SQLite tables in my Rails app look like. I've tried a lot of the suggestions I've seen online, but they all give me errors, or I'm not using the right commands.

Here's what I've been trying

```
rails db
```

(goes into sqlite db)

```
sqlite>.table
```

(shows relevant table)

```
sqlite>select * from table1;
```

Receive error:

```
Error: unknown command or invalid arguments:  "select". Enter ".help" for help
```

I've been trying to figure out why this won't work, but I'm a bit stumped.

Comment: This seems "impossible". What OS is this? What SQLite version (use the `.version` command for example)?

Comment: Are you typing `.select`, with a preceding dot, or `select`, without a dot? You should not type a preceding dot for any SQL command. Only SQLite-specific commands are preceded by dots.

Comment: If you're interested in the table structure for a Rails project, the [Annotate](https://github.com/brentgreeff/annotate) gem is really handy to see what's going on. Might be this isn't what you want at all, but think there's a chance it could be handy for ya.

Comment: Are you getting this error for all the tables in your DB?

Answer (score 1):

You can use DB browser for SQLite https://sqlitebrowser.org/ to view and manage SQLite database tables.